# Prevent Vi from exiting with an error code when my fingers are fat

Tags: vim

When I commit to git, I generally enter my message in Vi and then type `:wq` but just occasionally I miss and type `:Wq` which is clearly invalid. The problem is that when I do this, Vi exits with return code 1. Git sees this and thinks I aborted the commit and so I lose my commit message.

What I want is to still be able to abort a commit with `:cq` - so changing git to ignore the error is not ideal (although if no-one knows of anything else then I'd go for that) but to be able to still commit correctly when I've typed `:Wq` accidentally.

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense. If you `:Wq`, vim should spit an error at you but leave you still inside vim. Then if you execute the proper `:wq`, it would write and exit normally.

Comment: That is exactly what happens, then when I type :wq it writes the file and quits with a return code of 1 - which git rightly interprets to mean that the editor failed in some way.

Comment: That's not "exit normally" :-). My vim does not exhibit the behavior you describe. If I `:Wq` then `:wq`, vim exits status 0.

Comment: Good point. It seems that my Ubuntu box doesn't show this issue by MacOS does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add

```
cabbrev Wq wq
```

to your `.vimrc` file. This will make `:Wq` an alias for `:wq`.

Comment: I did this in March last year and had no problems until today when I typed `:WQ` :-(